# Adding a hyperlink with VBA--coding syntax

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, runtime-error

I am trying to add a hyperlink to the workbook data is pulled from to a summary workbook. I can get the filepath to populate the cell no problem but when I enter hyperlink.add I usually get a parameter error.

This provides me with the URL in the selected cell:

```
.offset(rowcount,112)=sXLFile
```

I tried this to add a hyperlink but I get a parameter error with the second comma after 'sXLFile' being highlighted:

```
hyperlinks.Add (anchor:=.Offset(rowcount, 112), address:= sXLFile,,, incidentreport & agentname)
```

What I think this could would do is make a hyperlink to the filepath saved in sXLFile and read as IncidentReportAgentName. When I reference the exact workbook/sheet in the code below I get a runtime error 13: Type Mismatch.

```
Workbooks("Incident Reports").Worksheets("Supplementary").Hyperlink.Add anchor:=.Offset(rowcount, 112), Address:=sXLFile, TextToDisplay:=IncidentReport & AgentName
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: To troubleshoot, first try replacing the variable (`xSLFile`) with a value.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by *"This provides me with the URL in the selected cell: `.offset(rowcount,112)=sXLFile`"*.  That does **not** refer to the selected cell.  This also does **not** assign a value to `sXLFile`.

Comment: What is the value of `sXLFile` when you get the error?  Also, if `.Offset(rowcount, 112)` = `sXLFile` then why are you referencing both of those? ie., if `.Offset(rowcount, 112)` = `sXLFile` then `... anchor:=.Offset(rowcount, 112), Address:=sXLFile ...` is making the cell link to itself...

Comment: No. 'sXLFile' does not give an error. sXLFile = ThisWorkBook.FullNameURLEncoded.  It returns the filepath of where the file is saved. I though I could use that as the hyperlink address. The error highlights the second "," or comma after sXLFile. When looking at the arguments needed for the Hyperlink.Add, I didn't want to add a subaddress or screentip and these are optional arguments. I thought I still needed to use the "," as a placemark for those arguments.

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand, I wasn't asking if it gives an error - I'm asking what the value of `sXLFile` is *when* you get the error.  If you're not sure how to check, add a temporary line *before the line where you get the error:*  `MsgBox sXLFile`

Comment: Sorry about that first comment. I hit enter expecting a linebreak and that's not what enter does in the comment section.  When I put a watch on the sXLFile and run the code it says <Can't Compile module>

Comment: So the code isn't running at all now?  A compile error is an unrelated problem and not caused by the watch.

Comment: When I try the second code up top, sXLFile is assigned the value of the filepath to where the .xlsm is saved but I get a subscript out of range error.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the watch, I thought that helped me know what value was assigned to something.

Comment: I think I know what's going on , I'll write it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple things going on.  You're trying to accomplish too much at once, so we'll need to take a step back.

**First issue** - you said:

> When looking at the arguments needed for the Hyperlink.Add, I didn't want to add a subaddress or screentip and these are optional arguments. I thought I still needed to use the "," as a placemark for those arguments.

Parameters for functions can be entered one of two ways:

```
FunctionName Parameter1Name:=Parameter1Value, Parameter2Name:=Parameter2Value, Parameter3Name:=Parameter3Value
```

...is equivalent to:

```
FunctionName Parameter1Value, Parameter2Value, Parameter3Value
```

...however the purpose of using the `Parameter1Name:=` is so that you can skip parameters or include them out-of-order without a problem.

So this:

```
FunctionName Parameter1Value, , Parameter3Value
```

...is the same as:

```
FunctionName Parameter1Name:=Parameter1Value, Parameter3Name:=Parameter3Value
```

...which is also the same as:

```
FunctionName Parameter3Name:=Parameter3Value, Parameter1Name:=Parameter1Value
```

Therefore, when you're specifying parameters with `:=`, **do not** add additional commas for missing parameters.

---

### Troubleshooting 101

If the correction above still does not solve you problem try this.

A couple early steps in troubleshooting should be:

1. Replace all variables and referenced values with the *actual* values. For example: instead of referring to an `Offset` to reference the location of the anchor, specify the *actual* range.

   - So instead of `anchor:=.Offset(rowcount, 112)`, specify `anchor:=Range("A1")` or whatever cell the link is supposed to be in.
   - Instead of `address:= sXLFile`, use `address:= "http://www.google.com` (or wherever the destination address is.
2. Simplify the expression as much as possible to get the basic functionality working.  For example, you don't *need* the "TextToDisplay" label right now to make your link work.  Get rid of it, temporarily.

So after those changes, your entire line should be a nice, simplified and *functioning*:

`Workbooks("Incident Reports").Worksheets("Supplementary").Hyperlink.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"), Address:= "http://www.google.com"`

If that's indeed doing what it is supposed to, *now* you can start changing the values to variables and adding more parameters...  but make ***a single change***, and then **test** it.  Then make the next change, and **test** it.  One change at a time.

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Hyperlinks.Add` Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel) (Excel)
- Chip Pearson : [**Debugging VBA**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: When I remove the extra commas I get a runtime error 9-subscript out of range.  I used sXLFile because the hyperlink will refer to a different document each time, so I can't use the static address. I need to address to change with each document. Am I not able to do that in this way?

Comment: @ashleedawg hyperlinks.remove?